# Why does Ruby 2.5.0 not show a stacktrace in Rails 5.1.4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here are two examples of the Rails server log for an error I encountered while only changing the Ruby version.

**Ruby 2.4.2**, Rails 5.1.4, Puma 3.11.0:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `recent' for #<Event:0x00007f08507bf8b8>:
  path/to/show.html.haml:50:in `block in _path_to_show_html_haml___4224769623360811234_28796540'
  path/to/show.html.haml:30:in `_path_to_show_html_haml___4224769623360811234_28796540'
```

**Ruby 2.5.0**, Rails 5.1.4, Puma 3.11.0:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `recent' for #<Event:0x00007f8ccc1b9508>:
```

What can I do to re-enable the stack trace in the Rails log? It doesn't look like there's a way to view which file/line number to look at.

To assist in investigating, I added this to my `ApplicationController`:

```
rescue_from Exception do |exception|
  byebug
  1+1
end
```

**Ruby 2.4.2**

```
(byebug) exception.backtrace
# A very large array of paths appears
```

**Ruby 2.5.0**

```
(byebug) exception.backtrace
nil
```

Comment: It's possible that Ruby 2.5's backtrace style is confusing the backtrace display method. Did anything change with the `backtrace` method's output?

Comment: Good call, `exception.backtrace` is showing nil. I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: [Some changes](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8661) were made to this method, so perhaps it's related somehow?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `binding_of_caller` gem in the Gemfile was out of date. I upgraded from `0.7.3` to `0.8.0` and the problem went away.

Comment: Thank you for this, I've been searching for a reason for quite a long time